# Scrollable all the way UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have this code linked to a button on a ViewController with a UITableView as subview:

```
-(IBAction)Action:(id)sender{


  [tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];

}
```

This makes tha tableView scrollable to the bottom so that I can use a couple of buttons I programatically added to the bottom. So far so good.

However, I want the tableView to be ok from the beginning, so I added the code inside viewDidLoad. Surprisingly, it doesn't work at all.

Could somebody give me a hand?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datasource methods are being fired after `viewDidLoad`, the tableView content size will be reset when it's loaded. You'll need to make sure you've called `reloadData` for the table before the code above. If you're using a UITableViewController, the order the methods are called is:

```
viewDidLoad
ViewWillAppear:
<your datasource methods>
ViewDidAppear:
```

However, if you want buttons at the end of table, you should put them in the `tableFooterView`. You can do this in interface builder easily by dragging a view to the bottom of the tableView. Or you can do it in code (in your `viewDidLoad` method, for example)

Per @Justin's answer... your question isn't very clear

Comment: Thanks. The tableView is getting the data from an array I have un viewDidLoad. Besides I have something else planed for the footerView.

Comment: I just added the code inside viewDidAppear and works great. Thanks!

Comment: I added them on the footer, but still I cannot scroll all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your trying to accomplish.  If your trying to access button on the bottom of a tableView why not use a Tableview Footer.

And if your trying to just scroll to the bottom of the tableview there is a method for that as well.

Need more info

Comment: Jason, I added the two buttons programatically as subViews of UITableView. I set the frame so that they will be at the bottom of the table. However, when trying to access them, the table bounces back. That's why I came up with the code I posted. The problem I found is that adding this code inside viewDidLoad, didn't work. I solved it thanks to @Ashley suggestion. However, following both of your suggestions I'll add the buttons inside the FooterView. I already have a code for that, so it shoudn't be too hard. Thanks a lot for your responses.