# Adding buttons to viewForFooterSection UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

after some discussion on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301560/scrollable-all-the-way-uitableview) I'm attemting to implement 2 buttons on the footerview on a UItableView. To create the buttons, I declare them on the declaration .h file, synthesized on the implementation .m file and then, I created them by code, like this:

```
- (UIButton *)resetButton{
if (resetButton == nil)
 {

 resetButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
 resetButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 40 , 95.0, 37.0);
 [resetButton setTitle:@"Reset" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 resetButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [resetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(resetAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    resetButton.tag = 1;    
 }
 return resetButton;
 }
```

and then, I implemented this code into the UITableView delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 100.0)];

        [customView addSubview:self.resetButton];
    [customView addSubview:self.calculateButton];

    return [customView autorelease];          
}
```

by doing so, the buttons appear on the screen however, when I tap them, nothing happens (I implemented a AlertView on the actions to check if they work.

any help here?

Thanks!

EDIT: the actions linked to the button:

```
-(IBAction)resetAction:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Reset"
                                                 message:@"You just pressed the Reset button"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Acknowledged"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

Comment: The example code looks ok. Have you checked the code in the action methods?

Comment: I just added it on my original post. But the button no even gets blue from the tapping...??

Comment: If I add the buttons directly, without the containes "customview" the buttons execute the actions, but they got streched horizontally and shrinked vertically. I tried to implement [customView bringSubViewTofront... but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are missing is `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

Without this the custom footer will be height 0. The reason you can still see the button is because `clipsToBounds` is `NO` by default for the custom view.